# How will the Bitcoin scalability problem affect every-day users in the future?

Tags: scalability

I get that this will cause transactions to take an extremely long time to process, but why is this a problem? Credit card transactions take about 1-3 days to process, yet many vendors still accept them. Will everyday stores and sellers not accept Bitcoin if transactions take too long?

Comment: Credit card transactions are accepted instantly by the credit card company; Bitcoin has no such equivalent feature. The CC company *instantly* agrees to the payment. The actual payment may happen later but it's definitely going to happen. Bitcoin transactions might be cancelled at any time before they're processed.

Comment: _"Bitcoin has no such equivalent feature"_ **Bitcoin has layers** Lightning payments are instant and depend on Bitcoin _"but it's definitely going to happen"_ **chargebacks are a big issue in credit cards apart from the privacy and security issues**